# find value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to find value in a multidimensional array, size of array is not defined. 
Let suppose user enters 1601 , result will be 011.
and if 1605 , the result will be 015 according to array

```
   array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'Zipcode' (length=7)
          1 => string 'Territory Code' (length=14)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '1601' (length=4)
          1 => string '011' (length=3)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '1602' (length=4)
          1 => string '012' (length=3)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '1603' (length=4)
          1 => string '013' (length=3)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '1604' (length=4)
          1 => string '014' (length=3)
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '1605' (length=4)
          1 => string '015' (length=3)
```

Comment: I answered, but what gets me is that all the index 1 values are 3 characters but show length 1?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Those must be some healthy characters only weighting 1/3 of a character.

Comment: I have an answer in your question. But I don't know if that is right based on your given question. It returns the 2nd index.

Answer (score 4):

If `Zipcode` is unique then you can do:

```
echo array_column($array, 1, 0)[1601];
```

Or if `Territory Code` is unique:

```
echo array_search(1601, array_column($array, 0, 1), true);
```

[`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) extracts a column from the multi-dimensional array to create a one dimensional array.

> array array_column ( array $input , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )

The second parameter `$column_key` defining which column you want to get from the multidimensional array as values into the one dimensional array. And the third parameter `$index_key` defining which column you want to use as keys for the one dimensional array which you get back. If `$index_key` is not defined, the array will be numerical enumerated.

**First code example**

So the first example extracts an array such as:

```
array(1601 => '011', 1602 => '012')
```

Using the value `1601` as the key you get the desired output `011`.

**Second code example**

The second example uses an array such as:

```
array('011' => 1601, '012' => 1602)
```

And searches for `1601` with [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the key `011`, which is the desired output.

See these two examples for what the second and third parameters do:

```
print_r(array_column($array, 1, 0));
print_r(array_column($array, 0, 1));
```

Comment: You can't write an answer without using `array_column()` anywhere, can't you :)?

Comment: Those are gems buddy!  :-)

Comment: @abraCadaver can you please explain 
echo array_column($array, 1, 0)[1601];
what are 1,0 values ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a nested function that does it:

```
$read=[
    ['Honar','607836545742426','IRO7P0001'],
    ['Danial','2304906587905','IRO7KHEP01'],
    ['Key'=>['sub_key'=>'sub_value']]
];

function is_exists_value($array,$needle){

    if(!is_array($array) || is_null($needle))
        exit("Error: check input");

    if (array_key_exists($needle, $array)){
        return true;
    }elseif(in_array($needle,$array)){
        return true;
    }else{
        foreach ($array as $value)
            if(is_array($value))
                if(is_exists_value($value,$needle))
                    return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(is_exists_value($read,"sub_value")); // Return True 
var_dump(is_exists_value($read,"Key")); // Return True
```